# Can I stop application remember last printer used

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, printer

Sometimes applications remember which printer you last use (or which setting eg 2:page).
I find this rather a pain - I would rather go back to the default (and give me the option to change default if I want to.

If it isn't possible, at least could someone explain when applications remember the printer and when they don't

Comment: What programs? Generally speaking programs always select the default printer, which is the point of a default printer.

Comment: I think it is MS Office programs that remember - will do some experiments to confirm